# Newrelic.js not working with Typescript NodeJs Express App

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, newrelic, ts-node

I want to integrate Newrelic for my Typescript NodeJs Express Application, I have done these changes

to install newrelic

```
npm install newrelic // to install newrelic
```

Added a file named newrelic.js outside src folder like this

```
'use strict'
exports.config = {
  app_name: ['App Name'],
  license_key: 'xxxx',
  allow_all_headers: true,
  attributes: {
    exclude: [
      'request.headers.cookie',
      'request.headers.authorization',
      'request.headers.proxyAuthorization',
      'request.headers.setCookie*',
      'request.headers.x*',
      'response.headers.cookie',
      'response.headers.authorization',
      'response.headers.proxyAuthorization',
      'response.headers.setCookie*',
      'response.headers.x*'
    ]
  }
}
```

with the correct app name and license_key.
And added

```
import newrelic from 'newrelic';
```

at the start of my index.ts file (which is the start of my application).
And I am using ts-node to start up my application like

```
ts-node src/index.ts
```

I am not seeing any data on my newrelic dashboard.
I tried searching **newrelic for typescript nodejs express app** but found nothing that will help.

Is something wrong here?

Comment: Were you ever able to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Encountered a similar problem, had hooked up the newrelic module as above but wasn't seeing any APM data in NR.  (I'm also using ts-node to run my apps.)

In the end, after reading the info on https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/configuration#node-flags and step 6 on https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/nodejs-agent/installation-configuration/install-nodejs-agent/ I updated the start command in my `package.json`
from

`"start": "ts-node -T -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src/index.ts",`

to

`"start": "NODE_OPTIONS='-r newrelic' ts-node -T -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src/index.ts",` to preload the newrelic module before starting the main app.

After that I started to see the APM data being collected